# An Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for the domain could not be contacted

Tags: active-directory, virtual-machines, hyper-v, domain-controller

I have a PC with Windows 11 Home. I use Hyper-V to install 2019 server (Server) and 2 Windows 10 Enterprise virtual machines (VMs). I add two Enterprise VMs on Server as follows.
I select MARVEL.local (domain name) and Computers (folder).
I right click on the space next to Active Directory Users and Computers.
I select New -> Computer and add Enterprise1 and Enterprise2 (computer names).
On Enterprise1, I click on System Properties and under Computer Name tab I click on Change… next to “To rename this computer or change its domain or workgroup, click Change”.
I click on Domain under Member of and enter “MARVEL.local”.
I receive an error. “An Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for the domain “MARVEL.local” could not be contacted.”
I enter “MARVEL” and succeed with an error. “Changing the Primary Domain DNS name of this computer to ** failed. This name will remain ‘MARVEL.local’.”
I try to do the same to Enterprise2 and after repeated trials succeed with an error. “Changing the Primary Domain DNS name of this computer to ** failed. This name will remain ‘MARVEL.local’.”
I have VMs use the DC (Server) as the primary DNS server.
I try something different. I delete both VMs from Server.  On Enterprise 1 I succeed after entering “MARVEL” for the domain name with repeated trials. On Enterprise 2 I never succeed. I have been in a snag.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a bit confusing, but you shouldn't do it like this.
When you want to change the domain name of domain joined computer, you should remove the computer from the domain on the device itself, and then reboot and join the computer to the domain again.
Try also to reset the computer account before rejoining

To able to join a computer to the domain, you usually need to set the dns server on the network interface to the ip address of the domain controller. That's what i always do.